# Stretch grid from code with width and height defined

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a grid which is defined at some point in my ViewModel.

I want to clip out some regions of this grid, then stretch it to a part of the screen and display it as an 'overlay' in the UI. To do the clipping, I need some sort of coordinates on the grid, but if I set its size, it refuses to stretch.

ViewModel:

```
Grid newGridMask = new Grid
{
    Width = 100.0,
    Height = 100.0,
    Background = Brushes.Black,
    Opacity = 0.5
};

//Clipping

GridMask = newGridMask;

//Does nothing:
//GridMask.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
//GridMask.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
```

View:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="MouseSpace" Background="Blue"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding GridMask}"/>

    //I tried this too:
    //<ContentControl Content="{Binding GridMask}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

The rectangle does show up as a darker rectangle on the blue background, but it is only 100 x 100 pixels. If the width and height is not set, the rectangle stretches, but I have no coordinates to work with. The clipping is commented out.

I could only find posts answering this where the width and height were not required for the grid, but if someone can point me to an answer or knows some trick, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you specify en explicit size by setting the `Width` and `Height` properties, the `Grid` won't be able to stretch to fill the available space. What part of the `Grid` do you want to display and where?

Comment: I use the grid as an overlay. I define some geometry objects - rectangles, circles, their intersections, unions, etc. - which I then use to clip out a section of the grid. The final geometry object is a 'PathGeometry'-object. ('GridMask.Clip = pathGeometry'). This works fine when I can predefine the width and the height. But I would like to do the geometry based on some independent coordinate system (100 x 100 or 1.0 x 1.0 for example) which can then be stretched to cover the parent grid in my View. Perhaps one can stretch the Geometry objects instead, but I am at a loss at that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague showed me an easy workaround:

Listening for `GridMask.SizeChanged` in the constructor and calling the clipping function from the `GridMask_SizeChanged` method. This gives us a coordinate system to work with from `GridMask.ActualWidth` and `GridMask.ActualHeight`.